# Using both TabBarController and NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

This is my storyboard:
[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Is my storyboard correct? Is there a way to use only one NavigationController for both the view? Thanks!

Comment: your storyboard is good enough ... and you need to use two navigation controller

Comment: Ok thank you then!

Comment: is it working good enough? or you facing any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed `UITabBarController` in `UINavigationController` and make both those `UIViewController`s in a `UITabBarController` which is in a single `UINavigationController`. Although storyboard doesn't allow you to embed `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController`. But you can achieve this result programmatically. Here's an example:

```
let tabbarController = TabBarController()
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)
```

Comment: What is the reason?